# find xpath for Continue with Google button issue

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

let's say I want to go to following website(https://www.zomato.com/) click > Login in > Continue with Google

the problem is, how to find this button "Continue with Google" button xpath? it's seem dynamic and always got NoSuchElement when run selenium (python), thank you

or do i need to switch frame/windows before find the xpath? And how it work?